# Correct Hook Only to Update Sub total in Woocommerce Checkout or Cart Page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

My Current code look like this:

```
function final_cart_update( $cart_object ) {
    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

            // get the custom pricing for this product
            $pricing_custom = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], '_number_field_1', true );


            // get product price
            $price = floatval( $cart_item['data']->get_price() );

            // set new price
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price + $pricing_custom );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'final_cart_update', 99, 1 );
```

This →

```
$pricing_custom = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], '_number_field_1', true );
```

is fetching information from this → 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awYG0.png)

In the front end, this is the arrangement → 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FavEd.png)

The final checkout page is coming like this →
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J99sj.png)

mathematics:

```
Variation Price: 49USD
Checkbox Price: 79USD
```

But the Product is getting updated. what I want is sub-total should get updated.

I tried this hook, but it doesn't work →

```
woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal
```

Please guide me.

**P.S.→** I am new so I do not have the right to embed the images.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915159/updating-cart-subtotal-in-woocommerce

Comment: That adds to total not to subtotal sir.