# WooCommerce: Updating subtotal is not updating the total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Hello i am pragmatically updating the subtotal_ex_tax however the total is ignoring these changes

I am using this in the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'custom_price', 10, 1);

WC()->cart->subtotal_ex_tax = 10;
```

I can see the value of subtotal change to 5$ however the total ignores the subtotal and does it's own calculation.

Comment: Those this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915159/updating-cart-subtotal-in-woocommerce

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Cart total price in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415783/change-cart-total-price-in-woocommerce)

Comment: Sorry these do not answer my question. My situation is very unique. I am changing the subtotal based on the number of items in the cart / mix of items in the cart so its easier to do all the calculation and return the subtotal then let woocomerce calculate the tax and shipment and give me the final total. is this not possible any more?
I also just ignore the per item cost and do not consider it at all.

Comment: any other ideas? @LoicTheAztec

Answer (score 0):

Incase this helps someone else. Instead of trying to update the subtotal. I instead change all the items to 0$ and make one item the same as the subtotal. It's not very clean and may not work for a lot of people. However, it works for my shop as I don't show price per item and only show the total price.